# Bind to Count of List where Typeof

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, inotifypropertychanged

I know how to Bind to Count, but how do I do it, if I only want the count where type is Product

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Items.Count}" />
Items = new ObservableCollection<object>();
```

I tried with a Property, But I am having problem keeping it in sync when Items are being added or removed.

```
    public int ProductCount
            {
                get
                {
                    return Items.Cast<object>().Count(item => item.GetType() == typeof (ProductViewModel));
                }
            }
```

Comment: have you tried using the LINQ TypeOf<T> extension method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Additional to getting the correct number of items matching the type you have to guarantee that the `PropertyChanged` event of the view model is raised when the item collection is changed. So basically what you need is something like this:

```
class ProductViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    private ObservableCollection<object> m_Items;
    public ObservableCollection<object> Items
    {
        get { return m_Items; }
        set 
        { 
            if(m_Items != null)
                m_Items.CollectionChanged -= HandleItemsCollectionChanged;

            m_Items = value; 
            m_Items.CollectionChanged += HandleItemsCollectionChanged; 

            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Items");
        }
    }

    public int ProductCount
    {
        get
        {
            return Items == null 
                ? 0 
                : Items.OfType<ProductViewModel>().Count();
        }
    }

    private void HandleItemsCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ProductCount");
    }
}
```

Comment: In the Items.Set method, I would unregister the previous event handler in case m_Items is not null.

Answer (score 5):

Using LINQ [OfType()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) you can return value of following statement in `ProductCount` property getter:

```
return Items.OfType<ProductViewModel>().Count();
```

BTW, to be more safe use following null-check condition:

```
return Items == null ? 0 : Items.OfType<ProductViewModel>().Count();
```

BTW2, avoid using of the [Cast<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) in such cases because it throws the [InvalidCastException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidcastexception.aspx) exception in case of invalid cast operation.

Comment: Had to accept the other answer, since it was more complete, but thanks a  lot for your answer, was very helpful.